# Find an array of Keys(a pattern) in an given array

Tags: java

Im working on this problem for 2 hrs now, and my mind stopped working. And Im getting no where. Can someone please help?

The question is match the exact pattern from a Key array to another array.
For example:

```
Key = {3, 8, 6}
Target = {3, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 2, 4}
```

the answer here would be the indexes at which these are found, which would be:

```
{5, 6, 7}
```

Comment: are you new to java and want to know how to do this in java?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. What exactly does not work?

Comment: Are you just looking for the first occurrence? Could there be multiple occurrences?

Comment: Thx for the reply, i will be looking for multiple occurrences actually. And I am actually experienced in Java, I can solve leetcode easy - medium problem, but somehow Im stuck on this and getting no where.

Comment: At least paste your code what you ave tried

Comment: Just FYI; 2 hours isn't a long time in programming terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves problem:

```
        int[] key = new int[]{3, 8, 6};
        int[] target = new int[]{3, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 2, 4};
        for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < key.length && (i + j) < target.length; j++) {
                if (target[i + j] != key[j]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == key.length && j != 0) {
                System.out.print("{");
                for (j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(i + j);
                    if (j != key.length - 1) {
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("}");
            }

        }
```

Comment: We want to find an array in the parent array and print the indexes that matches.

Comment: Yes, I have read the question, too. By "a little more information" I mean please don't post just code, tell the OP what the code does, that is *how* the code resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. @RahimDastar. This helped me a lot, finally got around the block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = { 1, 5, 7, 3, 6, 10, 9, 8, 3, 6, 7, 10, 9, 8 };
    int[] key = { 3, 6, 10 };
    List<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - key.length; i++) {
        pos = getPosition(i, a, key);
        if (pos != null)
            System.err.println(pos);
    }
}

private static List<Integer> getPosition(int i, int[] a, int[] key) {
    int count = 0;
    List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j = 0; i < a.length && j < key.length; i++, j++) {
        if (a[i] == key[j]) {
            count++;
            p.add(i);
        }
    }
    return count == key.length ? p : null;
}
```

Comment: What happens if we have number greater than 9?

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> maps = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, target.length).forEach(i -> {
        maps.put(target[i], i);
    });
    Arrays.stream(src).forEach(i -> {
        System.out.println(maps.get(i));
    });
```

Calculate the **index** firstly, it likes the **group by**, but only choose last. finally we can easily get the index from this **Hash**.

Comment: Could you explain what the i-> {} do? are those functional language syntax? I have only seen them in Javascript. Iam implmenting using a HashMap with indexes as values tho ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
char[]  key = {3, 8, 6};
    char[]  target = {3, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 2, 4};
    String keyStr = new String( key );
    String targetStr = new String( target );
    int start = targetStr.indexOf( keyStr );
    int[] resultArr = new int[key.length];
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = start; i< start + key.length; i++)
    {
        resultArr[ x] = i;
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( resultArr ));
```

if you want to match multiple times then use:

```
 char[] key = {3, 8, 6};
    char[] target = {3, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 6};
    String keyStr = new String( key );
    String targetStr = new String( target );

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( keyStr );
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( targetStr );
    // Check all occurrences
    while( matcher.find() )
    {
        System.out.print( "Start index: " + matcher.start() );
        System.out.print( " End index: " + matcher.end() );

        int start = matcher.start();
        int[] resultArr = new int[key.length];
        int x = 0;
        for( int i = start; i < start + key.length; i++ )
        {
            resultArr[x] = i;
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( resultArr ) );
    }
```

Comment: This is an intersting way, is this faster or slower than using a HashMap?

Comment: this pattern and matcher are actually very interesting, never seen it before. If I wanted to catch all the occurrences,  can I just do targetStr?indexOf(KeyStr, start+1), and keep looping until reaching target.length - key.length? Because everytime it reports the first index of the occurrence, and Icould just key.length-1 to the starting index to figure out the followings.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass through all the elements in the "target" array and also hold some index to follow after the currently match pattern from the "key" array, let's call this index "keyIndex". Every time that the element from the "target" array is equal to the element at the "keyIndex" position from the "key" array, you increment keyIndex (the currently match pattern is larger) and add to some data structure (I choose list) the index from the "target" array in which the elements are equal. If the elements are not equal, you should reset the "keyIdnex" (The currently match pattern is have length of zero) and clear the list.

I believe this should be good for you:

```
        public static List<Integer> findPattern(int[] key , int[] target){
           List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //This list hold the indexes of the patter

           int keyIndex = 0; //The index to follow after the "key" array
           for(int i = 0 ; i < target.length; i++){
               if(target[i] == key[keyIndex]){ //This "key" element is equal to the element from the "target"
                    result.add(i); //Add the index in which the elements are equal.
                    keyIndex++; //The currently match pattern is larger, increment "keyIndex"
                    if(result.size() == key.length) //The all pattern is checked and match, return the list which store the indexes
                        return result;
               }else{ //The pattern is not match anymore, reset all the data
                    keyIndex = 0;
                    i--;
                    result.clear();
              }
           }
           return null; //The pattern from "key" not found in "target" ,return null
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, but I spotted a problem with the code, it would return null if the key is {2,8,6} and target is {2,2,8,6}

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to decrement "i" in the else block, to start compare again with the previous element in "target". The solution edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subarrays of your target array with the length of your key array and compare each sub array with the key:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class OBJ {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] key    = {3, 8, 6};
        int[] target = {3, 6, 8, 8, 6, 3, 8, 6, 2, 4};
        for(int i = 0; i < target.length - key.length; i++){
            int[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(target, i, i+key.length);
            if(Arrays.equals(key,temp)){
                String indices =  IntStream.range(i, i+key.length).mapToObj(e->String.valueOf(e)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                System.out.println(indices);
            }
        }
    }
}
```